# XML Serialization on .NET for Oracle .insertxml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oracle

I've been studying up and prepping serialization of class objects. The purpose of my code is to pass a json string to a WCF that is stored in the following class object:

```
[XmlRoot("ROWSET")]
     public class Person
    {

    [XmlElement("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MIDDLE_NAME")]
    public string middle_name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LAST_NAME")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

}
```

Simple so far. Next, i have a code in place to serialize the object into XML and strip out the headerinformation in preparation to send the XML string to be passed to Oracle as a CLOB and then stored in a table. This is the result:

```
<ROWSET>
  <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
  <MIDDLE_NAME>James</MIDDLE_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
</ROWSET>
```

Now - that looks ready to send to Oracle to be inserted to a table. The problem is, I need to send it as Oracle XML format - known as Oracle Canonical format - which should be as:

```
<ROWSET>
  **<ROW>**
  <FIRST_NAME>John</FIRST_NAME>
  <MIDDLE_NAME>James</MIDDLE_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
  **</ROW>**
</ROWSET>"
```

I'm trying to understand serialize to a point where I want to insert  between the column data. Has anyone some something similar?

thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 1):

I would shape the DTO accordingly:

```
[XmlRoot("ROWSET")]
public class PersonRowSet
{
    [XmlElement("ROW")]
    public Person Item {get;set;}
    // ^^^ could perhaps be public List<Person> Items {get;set;}
}
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MIDDLE_NAME")]
    public string middle_name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LAST_NAME")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that you shouldn't need to "strip out" the header junk - if you configure the writer correctly it won't be added in the first place:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
    {
        var obj = new PersonRowSet
        {
            Item = new Person
            {
                first_name = "John",
                last_name = "Smith",
                middle_name = "James"
            }
        };
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonRowSet));
        ser.Serialize(xw, obj, ns);

    }
    string xml = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Incredible stuff - got most of it working just the way I wanted. One last question - I passed the object as person ie:  public string SavePersons(Person peeps) -- I would have to assign peeps to item if so how?

Comment: @dawriter new PersonRowSet { Item = peeps }